# Hyperledger Fabric: CA Server and Client on different machines or the same?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am new to Hyperledger and want to set a simple network.

Is it necessary to have a CA Client?
If yes, can they be on different machines?
If yes, can one of the machines be an Ubuntu machine while the other in Windows?

Comment: CA client is necessary. CA will enroll the user in the system and manage the cryptography contents. It can be on the same machine with Peer and orderer.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

1) Fabric CA is not required to actually use Fabric or to build client applications using any of the SDKs.  You can use any mechanism you want to generate X509 ECC key pairs.

2) That being said, Fabric CA provides a command line client which can access Fabric CA from anywhere (assuming that Fabric CA is reachable over the network).  All of the SDKs also provide clients for communicating with the Fabric CA and the Fabric CA also provides a RESTful API as well.